# DRG-10849 - Only when calling from higher level function

Tags: plsql, table-functions

I have several tiers of table functions which are used to perform a search. I have a `CTXCAT` index on the relevant tables.

When calling one particular function directly I recieve no errors and get the results I am expecting to see

However when I call a function which calls the function that works (mentioned above) I receive a `DRG-10849` error

```
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10849: catsearch does not support functional invocation
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.SEARCH", line 857
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.SEARCH", line 629
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.SEARCH", line 723
ORA-06512: at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SCHEMA.SEARCH", line 1181
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

`SCHEMA.SEARCH` line 857 is:

```
for r_count in c_count loop
```

The code for `c_count` is

```
cursor c_count is
  select 
    sum(cnt) cnt
  from
  (
    select
      count(*) cnt
    from
      synonyms
    where
      P_SEARCH IS NOT NULL AND
      catsearch(synonym_value, nvl(p_search, 'a'), '') > 0
    union all
    select
      count(*) cnt
    from synonyms
    where p_search is null  
  );
```

The function this is in is `SCHEMA.SEARCH.SYNONYM_SEARCH`. When I call this directly with :

```
select * from table(search.synonym_search(null))
```

I get the results I desire

However when I call the following:

```
select * from table(search.company_dictionary_search(null))
```

I get the error listed above

The code surrounding the `synonym_search` function is as follows:

```
select ss.score, ct.concept_id
  from table(search.synonym_search(p_search)) ss,
       term_synonym ts,
       concept_term ct,
       concept c,
       concept_types cts
 where ss.table_id = ts.SYNONYMS_ID
   and ts.TERM_ID = ct.TERM_ID
   and c.concept_id = ct.concept_id
   and c.concept_type_id = cts.concept_type_id
```

I don't know why this is happening but its causing me some major issues, as this is on a live system.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

The error has only arisen since I added the `UNION ALL` to the query

Comment: Oracle clearly mentioned the error `catsearch does not support functional invocation` Which means you cannot call a function from another function. You must look for some alternate

Comment: Okay, explain to me how its been working for the past 2 days?

Comment: I've edited my question to explain what caused the issue

Comment: `Okay, explain to me how its been working for the past 2 days?` No one except you can explain this. However try looking back what changes you did in past  2 days when it was working

Comment: It's only been since I added the UNION ALL